# Show probot logs in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, probot

In a simple Probot app (GitHub App) that is deployed to Heroku, I want to show log messages in the Heroku logs. I'm using the `app` reference as in the default examples in the Probot docs.

```
app.log('Yay, the app was loaded!');
```

I changed the log level in heroku which didn't help either. When started locally via `npm start` it works (logs are shown in the console).

I also tried:

```
console.log('Yay...');
app.log.info('Yay...');
```

Question: How can I see logs in Heroku from within a Probot app?

Comment: There are some mismatched quotation marks in your "also trieds" above.  Were those in your original tries?

Comment: No. They were correct. Didn't copy paste. Wrote them by hand and made a mistake when opening the question. Sorry.

Comment: Just fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Probot didn't actually start up because I didn't set the environment variables as described in the documentation.

> Configure the Heroku app, replacing the APP_ID and WEBHOOK_SECRET with the values > for those variables, and setting the path for the PRIVATE_KEY:
>
> ```
> $ heroku config:set APP_ID=aaa \
>      WEBHOOK_SECRET=bbb \
>      PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/Downloads/*.private-key.pem)"
> ```

I guess `APP_ID` is the important one.